# Express, blade with connect-assets

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, express.js

I have this CoffeeScript code running [here](http://chapter.zmgc.net) (with [TZM-Blade](https://github.com/TZM/tzm-blade)) and would like to have your opinion on how to better optimize it.

```
express = require "express"
gzippo = require "gzippo"
assets = require "connect-assets"
jsPaths = require "connect-assets-jspaths"
stylus = require "stylus"
blade = require "blade"
i18n = require "i18next"
http = require "http"
https = require "https"
fs = require "fs"
json = ""

#### Application initialization
# Create app instance.
app = express()

# Define Port
app.port = process.env.PORT or process.env.VMC_APP_PORT or process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT or 3000


# Config module exports has `setEnvironment` function that sets app settings depending on environment.
config = require "./config"
app.configure "production", "development", "testing", ->
  config.setEnvironment app.settings.env


# i18next init
i18n.init
  detectLngQS: "lang"
  ,ns: { namespaces: ['ns.common', 'ns.layout'], defaultNs: 'ns.common'}
  ,resSetPath: "./locales/__lng__/new.__ns__.json"
  ,ignoreRoutes: ["images/", "public/", "css/", "js/"]
  #,locales:['de', 'en', 'fr', 'pt']
  ,extension:".json"
  #,saveMissing: true
  #,sendMissingTo: 'all'
  ,debug: true


#### View initialization 
# Add Connect Assets.
app.use assets(build : true)
jsPaths assets, console.log

# Set the public folder as static assets.
app.use gzippo.staticGzip(process.cwd() + "/assets")
app.use gzippo.staticGzip(process.cwd() + "/public")
app.use express.favicon(process.cwd() + "/public/images/favicon.ico")
app.use express.logger('dev')
# Set the nowjs folder as static assets and locales for i18next
app.use gzippo.staticGzip(process.cwd() + "/nowjs")
app.use gzippo.staticGzip(process.cwd() + "/locales")
app.use gzippo.staticGzip(process.cwd() + "/data/topo")

# Set Blade View Engine and tell Express where our views are stored
app.set "view engine", "blade"
app.set "views", process.cwd() + "/views"


try
  app.set "chapters", require(process.cwd() + "/data/chapters.json")
  app.set "languages", require(process.cwd() + "/locales/config.json")
  app.set "translation", require(process.cwd() + "/locales/dev/translation.json")
catch e
  console.warn "files not found: " + e
  app.set "chapters", []
  app.set "languages", []
  app.set "translation", []
  next()
  return

# [Body parser middleware](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/middleware-bodyParser.html) parses JSON or XML bodies into `req.body` object
app.use express.bodyParser()

app.use i18n.handle
app.use blade.middleware(process.cwd() + "/views")
app.use app.router

#### Finalization
# Register i18next AppHelper so we can use the translate function in template
i18n.registerAppHelper(app)

# Initialize routes
routes = require "./routes"
app.locals.pretty=true
routes(app)

# Export application object
module.exports = app
```

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of all those commas:

```
i18n.init
  detectLngQS: "lang"
  ,ns: { namespaces: ['ns.common', 'ns.layout'], defaultNs: 'ns.common'}
  ,resSetPath: "./locales/__lng__/new.__ns__.json"
  ,...
```

CoffeScript doesn't need them:

```
i18n.init
  detectLngQS: "lang"
  ns: { namespaces: ['ns.common', 'ns.layout'], defaultNs: 'ns.common'}
  resSetPath: "./locales/__lng__/new.__ns__.json"
```